# Fire a trigger before inserting or updating the table, convert into JSON format and post the same on a URL

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a requirement in which I need to update the existing records with new values/insert the new records by converting the data into JSON via Oracle backend(pl/sql). These JSON values need to be posted on URL.I am able to post sample values on the URL via Oracle but before updating/inserting any new values, It throws a mutating error in the trigger when I try to read the table..Can you please post some sample code for this?

Thanks in advance

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER get_employees_trig before
     INSERT ON emp_table REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW FOR EACH     
    ROW DECLARE       V_RET VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('fired-0');
   IF :NEW.id <>:OLD.id THEN
    V_RET    := post_json_data_fnc(:NEW.id);
    dbms_output.put_line('fired-1');
     END IF;
    dbms_output.put_line('fired-2');
    END;

    create or replace FUNCTION post_json_data_fnc(
    p_id IN NUMBER)
    RETURN CLOB
    IS
    req utl_http.req;
    res utl_http.resp;
    url varchar2(200);
    l_clob CLOB;
    l_xml CLOB;
     l_txt CLOB;
```

--content varchar2(4000) := '{"name":"u14", "pass": "123","mail": "user@a.om"}';
        BEGIN

```
   URL := 'http://10.54.8.210:9200/temp/20';
   l_xml   := json_util_pkg.ref_cursor_to_json (emp_spec.get_employees(p_id));
   req := utl_http.begin_request(URL, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0');
   utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json');
   utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(l_xml));
   l_txt := l_xml;
   utl_http.write_text(req, l_txt);
  res := utl_http.get_response(req);
   utl_http.read_text(res,l_txt);
    UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(res);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_txt);
   return l_txt;
  EXCEPTION

  WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
  UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(res);
   END;




      create or replace FUNCTION post_json_data_fnc(
       p_id IN NUMBER)
      RETURN CLOB
       IS
      req utl_http.req;
      res utl_http.resp;
      url varchar2(200);
      l_clob CLOB;
      l_xml CLOB;
      l_txt CLOB;
     BEGIN

      URL := 'http';
     l_xml   := json_util_pkg.ref_cursor_to_json (emp_spec.get_employees(p_id));
      req := utl_http.begin_request(URL, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');
     utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0');
     utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json');
     utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(l_xml));
      l_txt := l_xml;
     utl_http.write_text(req, l_txt);
     res := utl_http.get_response(req);
     utl_http.read_text(res,l_txt);
     UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(res);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_txt);

    return l_txt;
     EXCEPTION

    WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
    UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(res);
     END;
```

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].

Comment: I posted the code...thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Get rid of this line `REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW` you don't use it anyway.

Comment: For triggers `BEFORE INSERT` the `:OLD.id` value is not available so the `IF :NEW.id <>:OLD.id THEN` line makes no sense

Comment: Thank you I changed my code and guess I am inserting/updating the code based on the id column alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the mutating table exception is being thrown because you cannot in general query the table on which a row-level trigger is defined (`emp_table` in this case) from within the trigger or within code called by that trigger.  My assumption is that something in the `json_util_pkg.ref_cursor_to_json (emp_spec.get_employees(p_id))` call is querying `emp_table`.  If you really, really wanted to do this from within a row-level trigger, you would need to remove any code that queries `emp_table` and recreate it using just the `:new` and `:old` pseudorecords.

However, you almost certainly don't want to do this or anything non-transactional in a trigger.  What happens, for example, if your transaction is rolled back?  Do you really want to have passed values to the web service that never actually existed in the table?  What happens if Oracle does a partial or complete rollback and then re-executes the transaction for write consistency?  Is your web service going to have a problem if you pass in duplicate data?  In addition, do you really want to tie the availability of your system to the availability of the web service?  So if the web server is down for a couple minutes, transactions on `emp_table` would fail?

It would make drastically more sense architecturally to build an asynchronous process.  In the simplest case, you'd insert the primary key from `emp_table` into a separate table like `emp_rows_to_be_processed`.  A background job (presumably using `dbms_scheduler`) would then periodically read that table, assemble the JSON, call the service, and then delete the row from `emp_rows_to_be_processed`.  That allows the database to continue functioning if the web service is down briefly.  The background job will only see rows that were actually committed.  It won't see duplicates.  And it doesn't have any problems with mutating tables.

Comment: Hi Justin,Thank you for your prompt reply..I have never used dbms_scheduler earlier..can you please throw some light as to how to schedule a job for inserting or updating any data in emp_table?

Comment: @user3929655 - I'm not completely sure that I understand the question.  If you're just asking how to use `dbms_scheduler`, here's a nice introduction from Tim Hall http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g.php  Assuming you move the trigger logic into a procedure, you probably just need to call `dbms_scheduler.create_job` with the new procedure you created.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Justin..My question is I want to understand the flow of the events happening in the above mentioned answer..I am very new to this I hope you understand ..do you mean to say that a new procedure in which insert operation needs to be performed on emp_rows_to_be_processed after emp_table?Is the sequence like schedule a job..insert INTO emp_table..INSERT INTO emp_rows_to_be_processed. ..convert to JSON ..call the service and post the data on the uRL? IF I am missing something kindly post your thoughts..

Comment: The new records will not be part of INSERT into emp_table ..the new set of records are to be present as JSON data alone..if my procedure can take all the column values as input paramters and then convert into JSON, post them on the url..can something like this be achieved without inserting into the emp_table?

Comment: @user3929655 - Some application is inserting data into `emp_table`.  Your trigger on `emp_table` should only insert the primary key into `emp_rows_to_be_processed` or some queue table.  The logic that you're trying to put in the trigger would then go into a separate procedure.  That procedure would get the key from `emp_rows_to_be_processed` and process the corresponding row from `emp_table` (generate the JSON, call the web service, etc.).  That procedure would be called periodically (say every minute or so) by a background job using `dbms_scheduler`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It really works..Kudos to your prompt reply and knowledge :)